# Cohort Analysis with SQL in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I try to implement a Cohort Analysis with SQL in two different cases. The first one has data in the format of

```
UserId, ApplicationDate, LastLogin
```

In this case, what I do is

```
SELECT 
        DATEPART(MONTH, uw.ApplicationDate) AS Month,
        COUNT(*) AS SignUps,
        SUM(CASE WHEN uw1.UserId IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)*100/COUNT(*) AS "1",
        SUM(CASE WHEN uw2.UserId IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)*100/COUNT(*) AS "2",
        SUM(CASE WHEN uw3.UserId IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)*100/COUNT(*) AS "3",
        ...
    FROM #users AS uw
    LEFT JOIN #users AS uw1 ON uw.UserId = uw1.UserId AND uw1.LastLogin> DATEADD(MONTH, 1, uw.ApplicationDate)
    LEFT JOIN #users AS uw2 ON uw.UserId = uw2.UserId AND uw1.LastLogin> DATEADD(MONTH, 2, uw.ApplicationDate)
    LEFT JOIN #users AS uw3 ON uw.UserId = uw3.UserId AND uw1.LastLogin> DATEADD(MONTH, 3, uw.ApplicationDate)
    ...
    GROUP BY DATEPART(month, uw.ApplicationDate)
    ORDER BY DATEPART(month, uw.ApplicationDate) ASC
```

This one works as I wanted to. However, the second case gets different input. It doesn't get the logins of a user, but the subscription orders. In the format of

```
UserId, OrderDate, PreviousExpiryDate, NextExpiryDate
```

In the latter, I want to group by month and then check for the next X months, which users are still active (that month should be between the PreviousExpiryDate and NextExpiryDate values)

**Edit for clarifications**

The Prev and Next day can be anything as long as the Prev is < to Next. There isn't a fix day. A user can order X months to add on his previous expiry date. So, it doesn't follow a specific pattern. The minimum gap is 1 month.

So why I try to achieve is

- For Month 1 and Year 2018, get all users that has an active subscription. This is checked from the Prev and Next by MONTH(prev) <= Month 1 and Year 2018 <= MONTH(next). To keep it simple, I don't care if the user had an active subscription for half of the month, as long as it was for at least one day.
- Then, go to Month 2 and Year 2018. How many of those that had an active subscription from previous month still have one?
- Continue for X months.

Comment: We need to see some sample sanitized table data for 2nd table.  Are prev and next the same day-of-the-month? Are they one-month increments? What about 31st of a 30-day month or of Feb? Are they all 1st of the month?    In the 2nd table, how are GAPs indicated?  Where a user fails to order at NextExpiry but instead waits 2 or 5 or 9 months without a subscription, and then restarts again?  Checking which users are still active implies joining 1st and 2nd tables.

Comment: Can you please tell me if it is more clear now?

Comment: We need to see some sample sanitized table data for 2nd table.